# why the program give "Segmentation fault" after 1018 try

Tags: c, servo

I'm writing a C code to open txt file and read two lines on it then print the value
it worked for 1018 time then it gives "Segmentation fault"
I've tried to flush the buffer but it don't work

```
while(running) {
    i = 0;
    if ((fptr = fopen("pwm.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! File cannot be opened.");
        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }
    fptr = fopen("pwm.txt","r");
    while (fgets(line,sizeof(line), fptr)){
        ppp[i]=atoi(line);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("%d %d\n",ppp[0],ppp[1]);
    rc_servo_send_pulse_us(ch, 2000);
    rc_usleep(1000000/frequency_hz);
}
```

Comment: Why do you open the file *twice*?

Comment: Why are you calling `open` twice?

Comment: This also seems like a good time to learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch crashes, and locate where in your code they happen. It will also allow you to examine variables and their values at the time and location of the crash, to help you understand what might have gone wrong.

Comment: the first time to try if the file is accessible or no

Comment: I used debugger it happened when it try to open the file

Comment: And why do you open the second time? You already have a valid pointer in `fptr`

Comment: How large is `ppp` array? Can it hold enough numbers for the whole file?

Comment: I removed the first fopen and it worked fine than you very much all

Comment: You should remove the second. `fopen` could still return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the file-opening is the likely culprit: On e.g. Linux there's a limit to how many files you can have open, and it typically defaults to `1024`. A few files are used for other things, and your program probably uses some other file-handles elsewhere, leaving only around 1018 left over.

So when you open the file twice, you *leak* the file handle from the first `fopen` call, and then your second `fopen` call will fail and give you a `NULL` pointer in return. And since you don't check for `NULL` the second time you attempt to use this `NULL` pointer and have a crash.

Simple solution: Remove the second and unchecked call to `fopen`.

Comment: I removed the first one and it worked fine than you very much

Comment: @MajdZahra The `fopen` call can still fail. You really need to check for that like you did in the first call.